# Changing tel: property working in simulator but Not in Device

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate, tel

I have changed tel property to do some string manipulation instead of calling that number.

its working in simulator but when i do it device, its still trying to call.

i have tried with webview, textview, button still same problem :(

Any idea?

---

Let me rephrase

By default, when clicked on any link with tel:xxxx iPhone calls number xxxx
But i don't want calling, instead i want to grab xxxx and append that value to my String.
How to do that.

### Thanks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.htmlString = [self createHTML];

    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [webView setOpaque:NO];
    [webView loadHTMLString:self.htmlString baseURL:nil];
}
- (NSMutableString *) createHTML {
    NSMutableString *tempString =[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"<div>"];
    [tempString appendString:@"John Smith"];
    [tempString appendFormat:@"<br> <a href='tel:201207415'>201207415</a>"];
    [tempString appendString:@"</div>"];
    return tempString;
}
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request     navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    //CAPTURE USER LINK-CLICK.
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    NSString *mytext =   [url absoluteString];
    NSLog(@"%@",mytext);
    myLabel.text = mytext;
    return YES;   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to call:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request     navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return NO;
}
```

Simulator cannot call anyway.

Comment: @user1147114 - What do you mean by `its not showing webview content at all`?

Comment: i mean, when i return NO, its display nothing on screen